# Вопрос про jquery UI datepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui

Заметил недавно, что в браузере Firefox не отображается календарь (input type="date"), сделал такой костыль:

```
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.datetime) {
    $('input[type="date"]').datepicker();
};
```

Но сразу же столкнулся с проблемой, теперь когда я выбираю дату, она отображается в инпуте в американском формате, как сделать так, чтобы она отображалась в формате дд.мм.гггг?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У него при создании есть параметр `dateFormat`.

Подробнее [здесь](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)